# Pl/Sql Trigger for changing default date format in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

i want to ensure that every time i logon the date format is changed from `'24-Apr-2014'` to `'24/04/2014'`

For that I created a pl/sql trigger as follows

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CHANGE_DATE_FORMAT
    AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
    BEGIN
    ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MM/DD/YYYY';
    END;
    /
```

However i am not logged on as sysdba so perhaps thats why i get the error

> ```
>     SQL> @C:/pl/dateTrigger.sql
>     AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
>            *
>     ERROR at line 2:
>     ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
> ```

What can i do to ensure that date format is changed permanently?

Comment: Hi Fazil, can you elaborate this little bit.
how you login? e.g. using SQL Plus , etc..

because, simply you can use 
connect sys/pwd as sysdba command

Comment: `nls_date_format` is generally something that is set on the client.  Is there a reason that you can't/ don't want to do this as a client-side configuration?  Are you saying that you do not and can not get privileges to create a logon trigger in the database?  And, taking a step back, what problem are you trying to solve?  When people are overly concerned about the `nls_date_format`, that often implies that application(s) are incorrectly relying on implicit string to date conversion.

Comment: Also, you could consider setting this in a `login.sql` user profile if it is just for you, or `glogin.sql` site profile if it's for all local command-line users. Bear in mind a logon trigger will apply to all clients, not just SQL*Plus - including JDBC, for example, which might cause confusion. And all users unless you selectively apply it within the trigger itself. You'd also have to use `execute immediate` to run an `alter session` command, it won't be recognised within PL/SQL as a simple statement.

Comment: You're definitely getting this error because you're missing the `CREATE TRIGGER` privilege.

Answer (score 1):

Your error means you are not allowed to create such a trigger. But your on the wrong track. You must set the default at database level.

## Setting Default Datetime Format Template

From [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_commands_1029.htm)

> The default datetime format template is specified either **explicitly** with the initialization parameter `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` or **implicitly** with the initialization parameter `NLS_TERRITORY`. You can change the default datetime formats for your session with the `ALTER SESSION` statement.

Then for your case this format must be set in your [database initialization parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96653/init_params.htm).

To check you have the right value in current session:

```
select value from v$parameter where upper(name)='NLS_DATE_FORMAT';
```