# how to get the date format in 'DD-MM-YY' format in ORACLE without using TO_CHAR?

Tags: sql, oracle

How do we convert a date in the 'DD-MM-YY' format **WITHOUT** using to_char ?
If I use the following query i get it in DD-Mon-YY format ?

```
select TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD-MM-YY') from dual ;
```

Output : 29-Mar-18

I want it in 29-03-18 format , **without using to_char**.
Is it possible ?

Comment: Why do you want that? Display is usually done on the client side.

Comment: It isn't the point of the question (though I'm not sure what is), but using `to_date()` on something that *is already a date* is just doing implicit conversion to a string using your NLS settings, before converting that string straight back to a date. It's pointless (though it may lose precision) and will break in a session with different NLS settings.

Comment: The output (without `to_char`)  is controlled by the SQL client you are using. You need to consult the manual of that on how to configure the display format of DATE or TIMESTAMP values

Comment: Calling `to_date` on a value that is already a DATE to convert that value to a DATE which it was to begin with is complete nonsense. Why are you doing that?

Comment: `to_char` really is the best option here; why are you trying to avoid using it?

Answer (score 3):

> How do we convert a date in the 'DD-MM-YY' format WITHOUT using to_char ?

This is a common misconception that dates in the database have a format.

A date does not have a format - it is [stored internally to the database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13568348/1509264) as 7-bytes (representing year, month, day, hour, minute and second) and it is not until whatever user interface you are using (i.e. SQL/Plus, SQL Developer, Java, etc) tries to display it to you, the user, and converts it into something you would find meaningful (usually a string) that the date is given a format so that you, the user, find it meaningful on the client software.

So the question you should be asking is:

> How do we get <insert name of SQL client software here> to change the default format it uses for a `DATE` data type?

If you are using SQL/Plus or SQL Developer then it will use the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter to format the date. You can [change this using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38547559/1509264):

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MM-YY';
```

Note: This is a session parameter and will only change the format for the current session (not for any other users or any subsequent sessions).

If you want to set this as the session default then you could set a [logon trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23276366/1509264) (if users are relying on the previous default format then applying this may not be well received).

You can also change the preferences in the SQL Developer GUI as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8134646/1509264).

> we dont have alter permission , its client db

Then use `TO_CHAR( date, format_model )` - that is what it is there for.

*Note: Please do not use 2-digit years as the expected format. It is a source of errors when dates are given an unexpected and wrong century.*

> If I use the following query i get it in DD-Mon-YY format ?
>
> ```
> select TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'DD-MM-YY') from dual ;
> ```

`TO_DATE( date_string, format_model )` takes two string arguments and Oracle will implicitly call `TO_CHAR` to convert your date to a string so it will match the expected data type and then when the client program formats it it will implicitly perform a similar transformation again. So your query is effectively:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         TO_DATE(
           TO_CHAR(
             SYSDATE,
             ( SELECT VALUE
               FROM   NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
               WHERE  PARAMETER = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT'
             )
           ),
           'DD-MM-YY'
         ),
         ( SELECT VALUE
           FROM   NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
           WHERE  PARAMETER = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT'
         )
       )
FROM   DUAL;
```

If the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is `MM-DD-YY` then `SYSDATE` will be implicitly converted to the default `MM-DD-YY` format then explicitly converted to a date using your format `DD-MM-YY`, and the day/month values will be swapped, before being converted back to the default `MM-DD-YY` format for display. Relying on implicit conversions is prone to many errors - try to avoid it.

If you want a date for your SQL client to format using their default format then just use:

```
SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL;
```

If you want to get a formatted date then use `TO_CHAR( date, format_model )`:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'DD-MM-YY' ) FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 2):

ALTER SESSION is one option:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd-mm-yy';

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
--------
29-03-18
```

Note that what you did - applied TO_DATE function to SYSDATE - is wrong. SYSDATE already returns DATE, so you could have applied TO_CHAR to it (with appropriate format mask), but not TO_DATE.

Comment: yes that was in my mind but i wanted to avoid to_char and also  avoid extract(year from sysdate) || - || extract(month from sysdate) || - ||

Comment: Is there anything you **don't** want to avoid?

Comment: @goonernike - this *does* avoid `to_char()`, and doesn't use `extract`...?

Comment: we dont have alter permission , its  client db

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use `TO_CHAR` or `nls_date_format` , though `EXTRACT` is an alternative if you want to answer an interview question.

```
SELECT EXTRACT (DAY FROM SYSDATE) 
       ||'-' 
       || LPAD(EXTRACT (MONTH FROM SYSDATE), 2, 0) 
       || '-' 
       || SUBSTR( EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE),-2)  as dt
FROM   DUAL;
```

Comment: I thought the same but in your case you get '29-03-2018', but not '29-03-18'

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan : Yeah... to make it yet more ugly ...:-)

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan : Thank you